# Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'factory_bot_rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I just installed the `factory_bot_rails` gem and it's giving me a problem right from the start:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/scan_spec.rb
    bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/rspec)
    Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'factory_bot_rails'.
    Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant FactoryBot
```

Based on the getting started documentation, I've done everything right:

> spec/factory_bot.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

> spec/rails_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_bot'
...
```

> Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise'
gem 'adminlte2-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'haikunator'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  gem 'pry-rescue'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

> Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      actionview (= 5.1.4)
      activejob (= 5.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.1.4)
      actionview (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
    activerecord (5.1.4)
      activemodel (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      arel (~> 8.0)
    activesupport (5.1.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    adminlte2-rails (0.0.6)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.4.1)
    arel (8.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (7.2.5)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    better_errors (2.4.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubi (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.8.0)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.0.0.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.19)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (9.1.0)
    capybara (2.17.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    childprocess (0.8.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.3)
    database_cleaner (1.6.2)
    debug_inspector (0.0.3)
    devise (4.4.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.2)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    erubi (1.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_bot (4.8.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_bot_rails (4.8.2)
      factory_bot (~> 4.8.2)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.8.7)
      i18n (>= 0.7)
    ffi (1.9.18)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.3)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.2)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    guard (2.14.2)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.12, < 2.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-bundler (2.1.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      guard (~> 2.2)
      guard-compat (~> 1.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-rails (0.8.1)
      guard (~> 2.11)
      guard-compat (~> 1.0)
    guard-rspec (4.7.3)
      guard (~> 2.1)
      guard-compat (~> 1.1)
      rspec (>= 2.99.0, < 4.0)
    haikunator (1.1.0)
    i18n (0.9.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    interception (0.5)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.1.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.12)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    nio4r (2.2.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    notiffany (0.1.1)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.21.0)
    pry (0.11.3)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
    pry-byebug (3.5.1)
      byebug (~> 9.1)
      pry (~> 0.10)
    pry-rails (0.3.6)
      pry (>= 0.10.4)
    pry-remote (0.1.8)
      pry (~> 0.9)
      slop (~> 3.0)
    pry-rescue (1.4.5)
      interception (>= 0.5)
      pry
    pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7)
      pry (>= 0.9.11)
    public_suffix (3.0.1)
    puma (3.11.2)
    rack (2.0.4)
    rack-test (0.8.2)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.1.4)
      actioncable (= 5.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      actionview (= 5.1.4)
      activejob (= 5.1.4)
      activemodel (= 5.1.4)
      activerecord (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.1.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_layout (1.0.41)
    railties (5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    rspec (3.7.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-core (3.7.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.7.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.7.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-rails (3.7.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-support (3.7.1)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.1)
    sass (3.5.5)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.8.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)
      spring (>= 0.9.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.1.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.1)
    turbolinks-source (5.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.5)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (3.5.1)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (3.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  adminlte2-rails
  better_errors
  byebug
  capybara (~> 2.13)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  database_cleaner
  devise
  factory_bot_rails
  faker
  font-awesome-rails
  guard-bundler
  guard-rails
  guard-rspec
  haikunator
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  launchy
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg (~> 0.21.0)
  pry-byebug
  pry-rails
  pry-remote
  pry-rescue
  pry-stack_explorer
  puma (~> 3.7)
  rails (~> 5.1.4)
  rails_layout
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-commands-rspec
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

I'm not even getting to the point where it attempts to actually load a factory model file that I've created.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add `gem 'factory_bot_rails'` to your Gemfile?

Comment: Please paste the gemfile.

Comment: @RafałPiekara added the Gemfile.

Comment: What's in your `Gemfile.lock`?

Answer (score 0):

Getting started says that you need to put `factory_bot.rb` in `support/factory_bot.rb` - you are putting it to the root of `spec` dir like I was.